# How to port C++ union to Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to port some code and now I've hit a sticky bit. The original code is in C++. I need to port a union that has two 32 bit ints (in an array) and a double.

So far I have:

```
I1 = UInt32(56) # arbitrary integer values for example
I2 = UInt32(1045195987)
# do transforms on I1 and I2 as per the code I'm porting
A = bits(I1)
B = bits(I2)
return parse(Float64, string(A,B))
```

Is this the way to do it? The string operation seems expensive. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: It may look hacky but `afloat64 = reinterpret(Float64,[I1;I2])[1]` could do the same. There are other ways you could do with `immutable` types and `unsafe` operations to get the same effect.

Comment: Oooh that looks way better. I'll try it out. I'm just learning the language and loving it. I decided the best way to learn it would be to convert some of our C++ code over to it. So far the learning experience has been great.

Comment: Looks like it only reinterpret's the first value in the array. reinterpret(Float64,[UInt32(101010100020),UInt32(1010001010)]) produces an InexactError

Comment: It is `UInt32(101010100020)` that gives `InexactError`. It gets an argument unrepresentable by 32 bit unsigned  integer. You should try other values as argument.

Comment: Please post the union definition and a sample of any specific C++ code you are trying to port. Otherwise we can only guess at the goal here.

Comment: After testing, my code doesn't work. The implementation details of Union are needed to understand how it would interpret the bit pattern of the UInt32s to a float. In my tests, the Julia float is very different from the C++ result. I'm trying to reverse engineer it now.

Answer (score 5):

I also come from mostly C/C++ programming, and this is what I do to handle the problem:

First, create an immutable type with two `UInt32` elements:

```
immutable MyType
    a::UInt32
    b::UInt32
end
```

Then you can convert a vector of `Float64` to that type with `reinterpret`.

For example:

```
julia> x = [1.5, 2.3]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.5
 2.3

julia> immutable MyType ; a::UInt32 ; b::UInt32 ; end

julia> y = reinterpret(MyType, x)
2-element Array{MyType,1}:
 MyType(0x00000000,0x3ff80000)
 MyType(0x66666666,0x40026666)

julia> x[1]
1.5

julia> y[1]
MyType(0x00000000,0x3ff80000)

julia> y[1].a
0x00000000

julia> y[1].b
0x3ff80000
```

Note: the two vectors still point to the same memory, so you can even update elements, using either type.

```
julia> x[1] = 10e91
1.0e92

julia> y[1].a
0xbf284e24

julia> y[1].b
0x53088ba3

julia> y[1] = MyType(1,2)
MyType(0x00000001,0x00000002)

julia> x[1]
4.2439915824e-314
```

Comment: That is close, but the original source has a two UInt32's becoming one Float64. I read up on Union and it's not the most popular feature of C++. My C++ coding days stopped 14 years ago so I am not sure if I ever even knew about union. However, the process in my OP seems to work. If I could get the reinterpret to not create an array, but a true 64 bit float from two 32 bit unsigned ints I'd be happy.

Comment: See this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/TI2xTobL3IM/u_i_hTFoBQAJ.

Comment: You can go in either direction. You can start with a vector of `UInt32`, reinterpret that into a vector of `MyType`, and reinterpret that into a vector of `Float64` as well. `[MyType(1,2), MyType(5,6)]` will create a vector of `MyType`.

Comment: @MattB. that was very helpful! I was able to see that any combination of stringing the bits of the Ints and parsing into a float were not working. I use words to examine a float, converted to bits and recreated with parse and it failed. So I'm back to square one, but with more information.